# PHP insert an order in a table with all the prizes

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a `shop` as a work for school and I have to add into a database the selections of the customer.

The insert is ok, however, in the `CommandeTotal` column, the prize is          only the one of the last item I choose (I choose 2 or more products who have different prize), here's my code to understand my problem:

The instruction for add into the table `Commandes` is ok.

The problem is when it's time to do the insert instruction for add into the table `commandeDetails`, the products are all inserted, but the prize for all the products in the table after the insert instruction is from the last product.

```
<?php
    if (empty($_SESSION["achats"]))
        echo "Votre panier est Vide!";
    else {
        //afficher les éléments du panier
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "magasin");
        mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");

        if (isset($_POST["PasserCommande"])) {
            //0) Pogner le ID du user logué
            if(isset($_SESSION["nom"]))
            {
                $queryUser = "SELECT MAX(UserID) AS No FROM Users WHERE UserName = '".$_SESSION["nom"]."'";
                $resultUser = $mysqli->query("$queryUser");
                $UserID = $resultUser->fetch_assoc()["No"];

                //1) Ajouter une commande(enlever CommandeID dans la requête)

                $queryOrder = "INSERT INTO commandes(UserID, CommandeDate) VALUES('".$UserID."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
                $mysqli->query($queryOrder);

                //2) Pogner le ID de la commande

                $queryOrderID = "SELECT MAX(CommandeID) AS id FROM commandes";
                $result = $mysqli->query($queryOrderID);

                $orderID = $result->fetch_assoc()["id"];

                echo"<h3>Résultat de votre commande : </h3>";

                echo "Commande # " . $orderID . " enregistrée.";

                //3) Ajouter des détails
                while ($element = each($_SESSION["achats"])) {
                    if(isset($_SESSION["prix"]))
                    {
                        $queryOrderDetail = "INSERT INTO detailcommande(CommandeID, ProduitID, CommandeTotal, CommandeDate) VALUES('".$orderID."','".$element["key"]."', '".$_SESSION["prix"]."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";                                
                        $mysqli->query($queryOrderDetail);
                        echo $queryOrderDetail;
                    }
                }

                unset($_SESSION["achats"]);
            }
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION["achats"])) {
            $total = 0;

            echo"<h3>Vos achats de la journée : </h3>";
            while ($element = each($_SESSION["achats"])) {

                $query = "SELECT * FROM produits WHERE ProduitID = '" . $element["key"] . "'";

                $result = $mysqli->query($query);

                $ligne = $result->fetch_assoc();

                echo"<div class='col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4'>
                    <div class='thumbnail'>

                        <div class='caption'>";
                            echo"<img src='IMAGES/max/$ligne[ProduitLien]'     width='100' height='50' />
                            <h4 class='pull-right'>$ligne[ProduitPrix]$</h4>
                            <h5><a href='#'>$ligne[ProduitNom]</a></h5>
                            <h6>Qté : $element[value]</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class='ratings'>
                            <p>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>";

                $total += $element["value"] * $ligne["ProduitPrix"];
                $_SESSION["prix"] = $ligne["ProduitPrix"];
            }

            echo "<div>total : <strong>" . $total . "$</strong></div>";
            echo "<div>total après taxes <strong>: " . round($total * 1.15,2) .      "$</strong></div>";    

        }
        $mysqli->close();
    }
    ?>

<form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="submit" name="PasserCommande" value="Commandez maintenant" />
</form>
```

Comment: As an example of my problem, I choose 2 product, the first one cost 64.99$ and the last one cost 45$, when the insert is done, all I see in the table's column `CommandeTotal` is 45$ for each products

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, I can only think of the following :

$_SESSION["achats"] is a array and isset($_SESSION["prix"]) is NOT(or having only 1 value)

For example, you have:

```
$_SESSION["achats"] = array( '1' => '1', '2' => '2'); 
$_SESSION["prix"] = "65"
```

Please provide more code, perhaps your input if this is not what you after.

Comment: I can't provide more code, because it's all the code in my PHP file

Comment: How does `$_SESSION["prix"]` looks like?

Comment: look in my code, all is there, when I do the insert in my table, the prize of all my products are the price of my last product that I choosed

Comment: Do you have a link of your website?

Answer (score 0):

I've sold the problem, I added this and it's working :

```
while ($element = each($_SESSION["achats"])) {
                $queryTest = "SELECT ProduitPrix FROM produits WHERE ProduitID = ". $element["key"];
                $res = $mysqli->query($queryTest);
                while($prixCommandes = $res->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $queryOrderDetail = "INSERT INTO detailcommande(CommandeID, ProduitID, CommandeTotal, CommandeDate) VALUES('".$orderID."','".$element["key"]."', '".$prixCommandes["ProduitPrix"]."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";                                
                    $mysqli->query($queryOrderDetail);
                }       
            }
```

Thank you for trying to help me